# SWIG: How to wrap byte[] structure member

Tags: c#, c, mono, swig

I'm using Swig 2.0.7 and trying to wrap a C library with SWIG to access it from C#.  This C library communicates with some custom hardware via USB, and so I need to be able to send/receive raw byte[] data to/from this library.  I have complete control over this C library, and can modify it any way that I need to make my life easier.

I've made good headway with my Swig wrapper, and I think that I've got it compiling fine sending strings in/out, as well sending byte[] data into the library.  However, I'm running into issues when trying to read data back out.

My packets are in a custom C structure that look like this:

```
typedef struct message_in message_in;
struct message_in {
    unsigned char* msg_data;    // Pointer to the data buffer received.
    int data_len;               // The total length of the data buffer received.
    char* dev_path;             // The device that sent us this message.
    message_in*  next;          // Used for the linked list
};
```

The function that retrieves this message from the C library looks like this:

```
message_in* hhcPopIncomingMessage();
```

I'm wrapping this with my .i file as follows:

```
%include "arrays_csharp.i"
// Attempt to use byte[] instead of SWIGTYPE_p_unsigned_char
%apply unsigned char OUTPUT[]  { unsigned char* msg_data }

// Mark this function as owning the memory that it receives, 
//   so that it knows to deallocate
%newobject hhcPopIncomingMessage;

// Mark this structure to use a custom destructor
%extend device_message_in {
    ~device_message_in() {
       hhcFreeMessageIn($self);
    }
}

// Ignore the Linked List member in the data strucutre
%ignore next;
```

The main trouble that I'm having is that -- while it seems to generate this structure just fine -- for the `msg_data` member, it's using the auto-generating SWIGTYPE_p_unsigned_char, instead of byte[].  The typemap that I applied changed the return value of the msg_data accessor, but it's still using SWIGTYPE_p_unsigned_char internally, and naturally won't compile:

```
  public byte[] msg_data {
    set {
      hiqusbPINVOKE.message_in_msg_data_set(swigCPtr, value);
    } 
    get {
      IntPtr cPtr = hiqusbPINVOKE.message_in_msg_data_get(swigCPtr);
      SWIGTYPE_p_unsigned_char ret = (cPtr == IntPtr.Zero) ? null : new SWIGTYPE_p_unsigned_char(cPtr, false);
      return ret;
    } 
  }
```

(the above fails to compile, with the errors:

```
error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `byte[]' to `System.IntPtr'
error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `SWIGTYPE_p_unsigned_char' to `byte[]'
```

What is the proper way to read the buffer out of my data structure as byte[]?

Thanks in advance for your help!

**Edit Update:**
I think I figured out the code that I want it to generate -- now I just don't know how to get SWIG to generate that code.

What it currently generates:

```
  public byte[] msg_data {
    set {
      hiqusbPINVOKE.hiq_hid_device_message_in_msg_data_set(swigCPtr, value);
    } 
    get {
      IntPtr cPtr = hiqusbPINVOKE.hiq_hid_device_message_in_msg_data_get(swigCPtr);
      SWIGTYPE_p_unsigned_char ret = (cPtr == IntPtr.Zero) ? null : new SWIGTYPE_p_unsigned_char(cPtr, false);
      return ret;
    } 
  }
```

What I want it to generate:

```
  public byte[] msg_data {
    // No 'set' member is needed, as this value is only ever read from this structure.
    get {
      int len = this.data_len;
      byte[] managedArray = new byte[len];
  IntPtr cPtr = hiqusbPINVOKE.hiq_hid_device_message_in_msg_data_get(swigCPtr);
      System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(cPtr, managedArray, 0, len);
      return managedArray;
    } 
  }
```